# I'm getting the error "Interaction has already been acknowledged."

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a bot with multiple **Slash commands** and what ever I do it's showing the error.

I tried .editReply(), even `if (interaction.replied = true) {interaction.replied = false}`

I use ES Modules, by the way. Heres my code:

```js
import {
   Client,
   EmbedBuilder,
   GatewayIntentBits,
   Routes,
   SlashCommandBuilder,
} from "discord.js";
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { REST } from "@discordjs/rest";

config();

const client = new Client({
   intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
   ],
});

const token = process.env.token;

const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(token);

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log(`${client.user.tag} is ready!`);
});

const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
   .setTitle("noobs.")
   .setColor("Aqua")
   .setDescription("hm.");

client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {
   // if (interaction.commandName == "ping") {
   //     interaction.reply({content: "pong!"})

   // }

   if (interaction.options.getString("food") == "gi") {
      interaction.reply({ content: "pong" });

      // if (interaction.replied = true) {
      //     interaction.replied = false
      // }

      if (interaction.options.getString("food") != "gi") {
         interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
      }
   }

   if ((interaction.commandName = "hello")) {
      interaction.reply({ content: "*gives love* hi" });
   }
});

const commands = [
   {
      name: "ping",
      description: "Replies with Pong!",
      options: [
         {
            name: "food",
            description: "ur mom",
            type: 3,
            required: true,
         },
      ],
   },

   {
      name: "hello",
      description: "Greets you with love.",
   },
];

async function main() {
   try {
      console.log("Loading application (/) commands.");
      await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), { body: commands });
      console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
}

main();

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Please, PLEASE, run a formatter on your code, for your own sake. Something like Prettier.

Comment: can you still answer it

Comment: After running a formatter, it's clear that your second "if (... != "gi")" is nested within another if statement - try making it an `else if` instead. Also, what error *are* you experiencing?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot just set `interaction.replied` to false. If you have already replied to the interaction you can only use `interaction.editReply()` or `interaction.followUp()`.
So try checking for `if(!interaction.replied) {}` and put your code into the curly braces.